# Neo4j ETL Tool: Connection failed. SQL state: S0001

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, neo4j, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to utilize **Neo4j** **ETL Tool** to Import Data From My **SQL Server Database** into the Neo4j Graph Database. I also **enabled TCP/IP 1433 Port** in **SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager** and **Authorized it by Firewall** and Imported Suitable **mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8 file for JDBC Driver** option. 
I already set

```
Connection name: test
Host:localhost
Type: MSSQL 
Database: my_database_name
Schema: my_db_schema
```

and here is **my** **connection URL:**

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TSQLV4
```

I set all of the options fines but When I aim to Test and Save the connection I encounter with this weird error:

```
Connection failed. SQL state: S0001, message: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:33b259b2-650a-4017-94fa-b86cfc657c9e
```

and My SQL Server Services are all run in the background among them:

- MSSQLSERVER
- MSSQLSERVER Agent
- MSSQLSERVER VSS Writer

do you have any idea to run the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did not create any user in `TSQLV4` database, just put the `integratedSecurity=true` at the end of your jdbc connection string like below:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TSQLV4;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Comment: Hi Mobin, when I try to use integratedSecurity=true, I get the following error: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.jdbc`: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load authentication DLL mssql-jdbc_auth-12.2.0.x64
Do you know how I can fix this error?

Comment: @Redink Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61117080/no-mssql-jdbc-auth-8-2-1-x64-in-java-library-path