# no mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.1.x64 in java.library.path

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, exception, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL DB in my Maven project, but keep getting following exception:

"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ...", "..Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.1.x64 in java.library.path....".

I've tried out suggestions from [no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707056/no-sqljdbc-auth-in-java-library-path) and [UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953643/unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-sqljdbc-auth-in-java-library-path) but it didn't work for me.

I've put the path to sqljdbc_auth.dll in:

1. Global PATH variable [Global PATH variable screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSJNL.png)
2. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uleGn.png)
3. pom.xml (as a configuration in surefire plugin dependency)
   [pom.xml screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFy0l.png)

And here is my code:

```
public class JDBC {

    @Test
    public  void test() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        String UserName="sa";
        String Password="Error911";
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String DB_URL ="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=QADB;integratedSecurity=true;";
        //OR by using ip
        //DB_URL ="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.104;databaseName=QADB;integratedSecurity=true;";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, UserName, Password);
    }
}
```

And the exception in console output:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not
>   configured for integrated authentication...........................
>
> ...Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.1.x64 in java.library.path:
>   [C:\Users\Automation\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL
>   Server\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\auth\x64]..
>   ....

Comment: Please, copy and paste the code as text, do not use the screenshot.

Comment: Edited the question, thank you:)

Answer (score 5):

it seems that you don't have the `mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.1.x64` file in your classpath.

As far as I know that file is included in the Microsoft SQL JDBC driver (`enu/auth/x64` folder): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

You can add that file to your classpath (for example copy it to: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin`) and fix the error.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem, and it took me hours to figure out.

1. Make sure that you're copying the `mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.1.x64` file and not the `sqljdbc_xa.dll` file into the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin folder`. According to the screenshot of your bin folder, I don't think this is the issue.
2. Restart Eclipse and run it again. I was copying the file into the bin folder with eclipse running and I had no success. Only after I restarted eclipse did the driver begin to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow below steps and it will surely turn out to fix "no mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.1.x64 in java.library.path" as well as "JDBC SQLServerException: “This driver is not configured for integrated authentication" issue.

1. Download `sqljdbc_<version>_enu.zip` from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 as per you Java version.
2. Unzip it, read install.txt and do as it says
3. Paste `mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.2.x64.dll` (present inside path -> C:/Program Files/Microsoft JDBC DRIVER 8.2 for SQL Server/sqljdbc_/enu/auth/x64 to
   Java/jre8/bin and to Java/jre8/lib

Comment: This should be the correct and accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

The suggestions in other answers will do the trick, but for me they were bit misleading.

Actually all you need to do is put the required version of `mssql-jdbc_auth-<version>.x64.dll` on system path -> add it to the **Path environment variable** to be able to find this dll.

You can obtain `mssql-jdbc_auth-<version>.x64.dll` by downloading the same version of mssql jdbc driver from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15#java-and-jdbc-specification-support
and extracting the mssql-jdbc_auth dll from `enu\auth\x64\` folder

Answer (score 0):

You should delete maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then:
add dependency JDBC driver jar manually [download here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

This is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to connect with the JDBC, you need to define the connection as follows:

```
  "jdbc:sqlserver://*******;authenticationScheme=NTLM;integratedSecurity=true;domain=******;databasename=**********;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;user=*******;password=*******;"
```

Use the following dependency:

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.jre8</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same issue, and i also went through the posts that you mentioned, i resolved it by adding the mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.2.x64.dll in \java\jre\bin\ instead of \java\bin. I was using a JDK and not a JRE.

Comment: This answer seems very similar to other answer posted before. Please make sure your answers are unique. I suggest you read [answer]