# Unable to load authentication DLL mssql-jdbc_auth-10.2.1.x64 (For MAC)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, dll

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server from a MAC and keep getting this error.

> Unable to load authentication DLL mssql-jdbc_auth-10.2.1.x64

For Windows, the solution is to add the dll file in the jdk/bin folder, but this doesn't work for mac.

What's the solution for MAC users?

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61117080/no-mssql-jdbc-auth-8-2-1-x64-in-java-library-path

Comment: I guess the question is: why do you need it? Azure AD authentication, etc., is built into the Microsoft JDBC driver itself as of around v8.2. If you're trying to do this for Windows Authentication against an SQL Server then you can only do that from Windows machines.